# CSS overflow-x: hidden not working when overflow: hidden worked

Tags: html, css

How would I use overflow-x: hidden on the body, but keep overflow-y: scroll?

I just put overflow: hidden on the body, and it worked (no scrolling on either axis). But when I try to specify an axis, like overflow-x: hidden, suddenly both axes become scrollable.

This should apply only to the body- I don't want to wrap anything inside a "wrapper" div.

This works, but cause both axes to not scroll:

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

This causes both axes to scroll:

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

The only thing inside the body is an absolutely positioned element.

Comment: Please show code, also a live example would be great

Comment: Your full code, for context

Answer (score 2):

I've concluded that this is probably a bug in WebKit. According to this link:

https://css-tricks.com/findingfixing-unintended-body-overflow/

the author mentions this exact problem of specifying an axis inside body. It looks like you would have to use a wrapper div, as mentioned in other questions.